# pointer assignment to a variable

Tags: c, pointers

`addr` is a parameter to the function and `read_value` is a local variable of the function. both are of type int.

Then what does:

```
read_value = (* (int *) (addr))
```

mean?

Answer (score 5):

`(int *) (addr)` casts the numeric value of `addr` to an `int *` pointer. Unless special care is taken, this operation is unsafe because an arbitrary value of `addr` can violate the alignment requirements for `int`. In general, if the value of `addr` is not a multiple of the size of an `int`, it can lead to a misaligned read which can eventually result in a `SIGBUS` signal.

The asterisk finally fetches the `int` value located at that address (called dereferencing) and saves it into `read_value`. It is at this point where the misaligned read can happen, if the address is not sufficiently aligned. The dereference might as well cause a segmentation fault if the address happens to be restricted or protected.

I would actually declare `addr` to be of type `uintptr_t`, rather than `int`, since that gives more safety between the cast to `int *`. `uintptr_t` should correspond to the size and the representation of a pointer, while the `int` type is semantically unrelated to a pointer.

Comment: Just to add here, this practice is known as "type punning". And as mentioned, it can be dangerous. If you can't be sure of the alignment, use `memcpy()` to read the `int` value instead.

Answer (score 1):

You cast `addr` to a pointer to int, dereference it, and put it in `read_value` .

If `addr` is really `int`, I think that it's undefined behavior.

Comment: It is only undefined behavior if the casts results in a value that cannot be represented. (See C11 6.3.2.3).

Answer (score 1):

Take the following example:

```
int read_value = 0;
int address = 0x1234;

read_value = *(int *) address;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
read_value = *(int *) 0x1234;
```

this reads an `int` at address `0x1234` and stores it in `read_value` object. It is done by first converting the `int` value `0x1234` to a pointer to `int` and then dereferencing the pointer to access the `int` value pointed at.

Note that the conversion `(int *) 0x1234` is implementation defined.

> (C99, 6.3.2.3p5) "An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation."

And the dereference of the pointer is undefined behavior if it is an invalid pointer or if it doesn't have the correct alignment. Any use of an invalid pointer is undefined behavior. An invalid pointer is a pointer that is not null but that doesn't point to a proper object or function.